# android app crash when i call EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, crash

The application crashes when I call EDITTEXT.

layout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/T_Price"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/B_LessMoney"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:text="@string/Price"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Main

```
    EditText mPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.T_Price);
```

and this the report

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: budgetreport.com.budgetreport, PID: 2791
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{budgetreport.com.budgetreport/budgetreport.com.budgetreport.Report}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:200)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
>                         at budgetreport.com.budgetreport.Report.(Report.java:21)
>                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2478)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2791 SIG: 9
>   Application terminated.

Comment: Show your activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `findViewById` before Activity's `onCreate` method (in the constructor?).

What you should do is to initialize it in the Activity's onCreate:

```
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    mPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.T_Price);
}
```